Does sparkworker need a restart after disabling backpressure in the spark streaming application
I have a spark streaming application (written in Java) and a sparkworker associated for executing the jobs.
I have set the following properties on the streaming application
spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled = false
spark.streaming.driver.writeAheadLog.batchingTimeout = 30000
spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition = 600
spark.streaming.kafka.maxRetries = 5
spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable = true
spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown = true

The streaming interval is set to 10 seconds while initializing the org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.JavaStreamingContext(SparkConf, Duration) object
This should make the application create a batch of size 6000 (600 maxRatePerPartion * 10 seconds). And since backpressure is disabled, my expectation is that the batch size will never go below 6000 as long as the number of records available in the kafka partition is more than 6000.
However, what I have observed is that initially after starting the application, the batch size is seen as 6000, but after a few minutes (or hours sometimes), the batch size drops significantly (even to 0) even when there are millions of records in kafka. I am logging this using the org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.StreamingListener.onBatchCompleted(StreamingListenerBatchCompleted) method
Note: I have restarted only the spark streaming application but not the spark worker after changing the backpressure from true to false.
Not sure if the worker needs a restart too.
Also, please let me know if there is another related configuration that makes the batch size drop.

Streaming or structured streaming?

@Ged, streaming (not structured streaming)
